# e-commerce sites that using SPA approach and have a SEO

Tags: seo, google, ecommerce

I'm building an Enterprise size e-commerce site, using nodejs+angularjs, now I have a huge issue with seo, what huge sites that using SPA approach you are familiar with?

What are the best practice approaches you suggest me to implement it?

Comment: Instead of asking for "best" maybe you could say what the problems you are having are and ask how to solve specific issues.

Answer (score 0):

With AngularJS Apps, the important part is to **prerender** the page, so that the cached version of it exists in memory and you avoid writing to disk to grab the 'idealised' version of page.

See [Prerender.io](https://prerender.io/) for the SaaS and the [Open Source version on GitHub](https://github.com/prerender/prerender).

Be sure to check the 'Middleware' resource to suit your need for publishing it.

The cached version of your Angular App is also important for performance reasons, as Google Users expect speed so sending multiple requests from the get-go cold delay the perceived load time of your app.

This is crucial if your eCommerce App is Retail and you are attempting to compete for brand name terms, since those terms have high conversion value and Structured Data of Rich Snippets would be important to get right.

If you are using Structured Data, be sure to be wary of `ng-repeat` as you might be in danger of creating orphans or duplicate references, so please ensure that you have a very tight and defined scope on your Microdata or use the JSON-LD syntax where supported.

It is important to design the IA, so you avoid circumstances like `example.com/fragrances/for-her` and `example.com/for-her/fragrances` so that they have the appropriate canonical URL - so some kind of silo hierarchy is important here.